# Retornar quantidade de registros usando a foreign key

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Eu tenho a seguinte tabela

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu quero selecionar apenas os dois primeiros registros de cada status_id, estou usando o MYSQL.

Não tenho como utilizar o LIMIT apenas por que ai não vou conseguir a quantidade de 2 registros pelo status_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível resolver utilizando CTE. (Common Table Expression)

Pode seguir com o código abaixo para sua tabela.
Para seguir com o filtro na quantidade que desejar eliminar da repetição, é só alterar o 'repetição < x'

```
WITH registrosTratados
AS (SELECT 
       id,
    nome,
    status_id,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
          PARTITION BY status_id 
          ORDER BY id) repeticao
    FROM 
       registros
   )
   
SELECT 
   id,
   nome,
   status_id,
   repeticao
FROM 
   registrosTratados
WHERE 
   repeticao < 3
  order by id;
```

[image: Registros na tabela]

[image: Resultado da query]

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou exatamente como eu queria.